# Is there a Julia Project.toml keyword to run commands like `npm start`?

Tags: julia

The recommendation to run a Julia project is to run `julia --project=. nameOfScript.jl`.

Julia projects are reminiscent of npm projects, setting up src and tests directories, adding dependencies to `Project.toml` and locking dependencies version in `Manifest.toml`, but I'm not finding any keywords equivalent to `scripts` from `package.json`.

Are there keywords to run Julia script automatically from the Project file easily like `npm start`, `npm test`, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe the fields and sections listed in [the docs](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/toml-files/) are exhaustive. The package manager parses this information but isn't intended to evaluate any code in the file.

Depending on your intent, an alternative might be to include instructions in the startup file, which is executed by default. From `julia --help`:

```
 --startup-file={yes*|no}   Load `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH/config/startup.jl`; if `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`
                            environment variable is unset, load `~/.julia/config/startup.jl`
```